# Difference between "codecvt_utf8_utf16" and "codecvt_utf8" for converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, codecvt

I came across two code snippets

```
std::wstring str = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>().from_bytes("some utf8 string");
```

and,

```
std::wstring str = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().from_bytes("some utf8 string");
```

Are they both correct ways to convert utf-8 stored in `std::string` to utf-16 in `std::wstring`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`codecvt_utf8_utf16` does exactly what it says: converts between UTF-8 and UTF-16, both of which are well-understood and portable encodings.

`codecvt_utf8` converts between UTF-8 and UCS-2/4 (depending on the size of the given type). UCS-2 and UTF-16 are *not the same thing*.

So if your goal is to store genuine, actual UTF-16 in a `wchar_t`, then you should use `codecvt_utf8_utf16`. However, if you're trying to do cross-platform coding with `wchar_t` as some kind of Unicode-ish thing or whatever, you can't. The UTF-16 facet always converts to UTF-16, whereas `wchar_t` on non-Windows platforms is expected to generally be UTF-32/UCS-4. By contrast, `codecvt_utf8` only converts to UCS-2/4, but on Windows, `wchar_t` strings are "supposed" to be full UTF-16.

So you can't write code to satisfy all platforms without some `#ifdef` or template work. On Windows, you should use `codecvt_utf8_utf16`; on non-Windows, you should use `codecvt_utf8`.

Or better yet, just use UTF-8 internally and find APIs that directly take strings in a specific format rather than platform-dependent `wchar_t` stuff.

Comment: Do you recommend using ICU library because `codecvt` will get deprecated? I can't find enough examples to use ICU to do what I am trying to do. Does it also have one line code like I have wrote in question to do the job?

Comment: @user963241: `codecvt` has already been deprecated. It's still available though; deprecated does not mean "removed". I would recommend a real Unicode library regardless though, since `codecvt` is pretty terrible.

Comment: Thanks, can I still use it safely as long as I don't use C++17?

Comment: @user963241: "deprecated" *does not mean "removed"*. You can safely use it in *all* versions of C++ until it actually gets removed.